# Как обучить искусственную нейронную сеть таблице умножения?

Tags: javascript, математика, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Есть необходимость создания нейронной сети для моделирования расчетов по некоторым формулам. Начал с банальной таблицы умножения и облом. То ли с [Brain.js](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js) что-то не так, то ли я не понял принципа обучения нейронных сетей...

Алгоритм следующий:

1. Нормализуем данные - принимаем, что на входе и выходе сети должны быть значения в диапазоне [0, 1]. Диапазон исходных значений входных данных [0,10], а выходных [0,100]. Берем соответствующие [формулы нормализации и денормализации](https://neuronus.com/theory/nn/925-sposoby-normalizatsii-peremennykh.html):

> Xn[i] = ( X[i] - Xmin ) / ( Xmax - Xmin ) = ( X[i] - 0) / ( 10 - 0 ) = X[i] / 10;
>   Yn[j] = ( Y[j] - Ymin ) / ( Ymax - Ymin ) = ( Y[j] - 0) / ( 100 - 0 ) = Y[j] / 100;
>   Y[j] = Ymin + Y[j] * ( Ymax - Ymin ) = Y[j] * 100;

2. Определяем функцию активации

> sigmoid

3. Генерируем обучающий набор - массив элементов

> {
>       input : [ norm(i), norm(j) ],
>       output: [ norm( i * j )    ]
>   }

```
Нормализованные входные значения: norm(i) и norm(j)
Нормализованное выходное значение: norm( i * j )
```

4. Обучаю нейронную сеть.... и получаю полную фигню...

В коде это выглядит так (после задержки, вызванной обучением выдается результат проверки):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://brain.js.org/browser.js"></script></head>
<body><script>
    var norm = function ( val, min, max ) {
      return ( val - min ) / ( max - min );
    };
    var denorm = function ( val, min, max ) {
      return min + val * ( max - min );
    };
    var input = function ( val ) {
      return norm( val, 0, 10 );
    }
    var output = function ( val ) {
      return norm( val, 0, 100 );
    }
    var result = function ( val ) {
      return denorm( val, 0, 100 );
    };

    var data = [];
    for ( var i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
      for ( var j = 1; j < 10; j++ ) {
        data.push({
          input : [ input( i ), input( j ) ],
          output: [ output( i*j ) ]
        });
      }
    }


    var cpsnet = new brain.NeuralNetwork({
        binaryThresh: 0.5,
        hiddenLayers: [30,20,10],
        activation: 'sigmoid',
        leakyReluAlpha: 0.0001
    });

    cpsnet.train( data );

    console.log( '1 * 9 = ' + result( cpsnet.run([ input(1), input(9) ]) ) );
    console.log( '2 * 8 = ' + result( cpsnet.run([ input(2), input(8) ]) ) );
    console.log( '5 * 5 = ' + result( cpsnet.run([ input(5), input(5) ]) ) );
    console.log( '9 * 9 = ' + result( cpsnet.run([ input(9), input(9) ]) ) );
</script></body>
</html>
```

Как видно - результат далёк от ожидаемого...

Тестовый пример библиотеки прекрасно работает:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://brain.js.org/browser.js"></script></head>
<body><script>
    var mynet = new brain.NeuralNetwork({
        binaryThresh: 0.5,
        hiddenLayers: [3],
        activation: 'sigmoid'
    });

    mynet.train([
        {input: [0, 0], output: [0]},
        {input: [0, 1], output: [1]},
        {input: [1, 0], output: [1]},
        {input: [1, 1], output: [0]}
    ]);

    console.log( '0 xor 0 = ' + mynet.run([0, 0]) );
    console.log( '0 xor 1 = ' + mynet.run([0, 1]) );
    console.log( '1 xor 1 = ' + mynet.run([1, 0]) );
    console.log( '1 xor 1 = ' + mynet.run([1, 1]) )
</script></body>
</html>
```

В связи с этим вопрос - что же я делаю не так ?

Comment: расскажите больше про Вашу сеть, почему она такая, я не открывал доку и полагаю что тут у Вас 3 слоя по 30, 20 и 10 нейронов?

Comment: Порог ошибки по умолчанию `0.005` - слишком высокий для Ваших данных. Уменьшите его, например: `cpsnet.train( data, {errorThresh: 0.00001})`, и будет Вам счастье.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Это тестовая сеть, для моделирования вычислений на сети, на примере простейшего варианта - обычной таблицы умножения. Параметры выбраны случайно, надеюсь избыточно. Как только получится заставить сеть работать правильно, и с достоверностью более 0.9 буду уменьшать размеры, и проверять работу на данных не входящих в обучающий набор.

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо, действительно стало лучше, например, 1x9 = 10.045 и 2x8 = 15.6023 и 5x5 = 25.2762 и 9x9 = 80.0097. Есть способ повысить точность, хотя бы на обучающем наборе ?

Comment: Ну, уменьшайте порог, увеличивайте число итераций (для 0.00001 оно обрывается на умолчальных 20000 итерациях, не доходя до этой точности)

Comment: @Yaant Благодарю. Добился не ниже 0.97 на тестовом наборе. Время обучения сети порядка 6 минут. Интересно сколько будет, если входов будет хотя бы 20. Вопрос закрыт. Можете свой комментарий сделать ответом, с примером кода - для будущих поколений))